# jquery disable item options if a certain value is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm stuck with a jquery problem .. I actually want to disable all the  (from all other  items except the parent one) if the selected value is "interestingValue"

```
    <select name="menufoo" id="menufoo" class="menufooClass">
      <option value="interestingValue">bar foo</option>
      <option value="foo1">foo abc1</option>
      <option value="bar1">foo abc1</option>
    </select>

    <select name="menufoo2" id="menufoo2" class="menufooClass2">
      <option value="interestingValue2">bar foo2</option>
      <option value="foo2">foo abc2</option>
      <option value="bar2">foo abc2</option>
    </select>
```

ex : if we select "interestingValue" from the first menu we get

```
    <select name="menufoo" id="menufoo" class="menufooClass">
      <option value="interestingValue">bar foo</option>
      <option value="foo1">foo abc1</option>
      <option value="bar1">foo abc1</option>
    </select>

    <select name="menufoo2" id="menufoo2" class="menufooClass2">
      <option value="interestingValue2" disabled="disabled">bar foo2</option>
      <option value="foo2" disabled="disabled">foo abc2</option>
      <option value="bar2" disabled="disabled">foo abc2</option>
    </select>
```

ex :  if we select "interestingValue2" from the second menu we get

```
    <select name="menufoo" id="menufoo" class="menufooClass">
      <option value="interestingValue" disabled="disabled">bar foo</option>
      <option value="foo1" disabled="disabled">foo abc1</option>
      <option value="bar1" disabled="disabled">foo abc1</option>
    </select>

    <select name="menufoo2" id="menufoo2" class="menufooClass2">
      <option value="interestingValue2">bar foo2</option>
      <option value="foo2">foo abc2</option>
      <option value="bar2">foo abc2</option>
    </select>
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your select tags are siblings you can try:

```
$('select').change(function(){
  if (this.selectedIndex == 0) {
     $(this).siblings('select').find('option').prop('disabled', true)
  }
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8K2jA/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get it, but something like this:

```
$('[id^=menufoo]').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value.indexOf('interestingValue') != -1 ) {
        $('[id^=menufoo]').not(this).find('option').prop('disabled', true);
    }else{
        $('[id^=menufoo]').find('option').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uEJAQ/2/)

Comment: Just make sure though that when using id^=menufoo as a selector, make sure that you do not have a select with id starting with menufoo where you do not want the event handler to be applied to nor have its options disabled as a result of selecting interestingValue in other selectmenus.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an onchange event to both select items and check whether the new select value is equivalent to interestingValue for the first menu and interestingValue2 from the second menu. You can use .prop() to disable this.

You can do something like this:

```
$("#menufoo").bind("change", function(event){

  $("#menufoo2").find("option").prop("disabled", ($(this).val() == "interestingValue"));

});

$("#menufoo2").bind("change", function(event){
  $("#menufoo").find("option").prop("disabled", ($(this).val() == "interestingValue2"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#menufoo").change(function (){
    if($("#menufoo option:selected").val()=="interestingValue")
        $('.menufooClass2 option').attr('disabled','disabled');
  });
    $("#menufoo2").change(function (){
    if($("#menufoo2 option:selected").val()=="interestingValue2")
        $('.menufooClass option').attr('disabled','disabled');
  });


});
</script>   


   <select name="menufoo" id="menufoo" class="menufooClass">
      <option value="interestingValue">bar foo</option>
      <option value="foo1">foo abc1</option>
      <option value="bar1">foo abc1</option>
    </select>

        <select name="menufoo2" id="menufoo2" class="menufooClass2">
      <option value="interestingValue2">bar foo2</option>
      <option value="foo2">foo abc2</option>
      <option value="bar2">foo abc2</option>
    </select>
```